# ag-grid - data transfer between two grids using drag and drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, angular5, ag-grid

I am using `ag-Grid` with `Angular 5`. I have a requirement where data has to be transferred between two grids using mouse drag and drop. As per the opened [issue](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2241)  this feature is not supported by `ag-Grid`.

Could you suggest any workaround?

Comment: If it doesn't have to be drag and drop, you could make something [like this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3418/what-is-the-best-ui-for-multi-selecting-from-a-list/3419#3419).

Comment: Thank you. drag and drop is a must requirement :(

Answer (score 0):

This seems supported now: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-drag-and-drop/#dragging-between-grids

It is quite messy to find the target row and style it, if you need more than a destination element for the drag. It could be improved like with some kind of row drag end event, though the team comments on lack of events on destination grid:

> Note that there is no specific drop zone logic in the grid. This was done on purpose after analysis. On initial analysis consideration was given to exposing callbacks or firing events in the grid for the drop zone relevant events e.g. ondragenter, on dragexit etc. However this did not add any additional value given that the developer can easily add such event listeners to the grid div directly, and that the grid would be simply exposing the underlying events / callbacks rather than doing any processing itself. Given the grid was not adding any value, providing such callbacks would just be adding a layer of useless logic.